# How can I add an extra field to a proxied model in Django?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-taggit

I'm specifically talking about the Tag model, which I have no much experience with. The code goes like this:

```
@register_snippet
class ArticleTag(index.Indexed,Tag):

class Meta:
    proxy=True

search_fields = [
    index.SearchField('name', partial_match=True),
    index.SearchField('slug', partial_match=True),
]
```

The Tag model has two fields, 'name' and 'slug'. But now I want to add a third custom field named 'type' that will be simply a CharField.

I tried modifying it like this:

```
@register_snippet
class ArticleTag(index.Indexed,Tag):

class Meta:
    proxy=True

search_fields = [
    index.SearchField('name', partial_match=True),
    index.SearchField('slug', partial_match=True),
]

merge_to = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

panels = [
    FieldPanel('name'),
    FieldPanel('slug'),
    FieldPanel('type'),
]
```

However the server yields:

```
ERRORS:
?: (models.E017) Proxy model 'ArticleTag' contains model fields.
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your tag gas to inherit from `TagBase` and you'll have to create a custom through model. The `django-taggit` documentation has [an example on how to create custom tags](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#custom-tag).

Answer (score 0):

We can do this below trick :P

```
class Model(object):
    '''
    Skip extra field validation "models.E017"
    '''

    @classmethod
    def _check_model(cls):
        errors = []
        return errors

@register_snippet
class ArticleTag(Model, index.Indexed,Tag):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```